# PCF Credhub Service broker - Unable to rotate credentials and demands restart

Tags: cloud-foundry

I created a `credhub` instance and stored my secrets using below `cf command`

> cf create-service credhub default my-secrets -c "{\"secretMessage\":\"1234567\"}"

My spring boot app picks up the `secretMessage` value without any issue. And now i executed `update-service` command and rotated the `secretMessage` with the below command

> cf update-service my-secrets -c "{\"secretMessage\":\"1234567-updated\"}"

But my spring-boot app isn't picking the updated one unless and untill I restart the app in PCF.

Is there any way to pick up the rotated-credentials without restart ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But my spring-boot app isn't picking the updated one unless and untill I restart the app in PCF.
>
> Is there any way to pick up the rotated-credentials without restart ?

No, that is the expected behavior.

https://docs.pivotal.io/credhub-service-broker/using.html#update

Your service instance is bound to your app. Like all service instances bound to an app, it's providing information through the `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable. Environment variables, including `VCAP_SERVICES`, are only updated when you restart the app.

You might be thinking, wait my `VCAP_SERVICES` has placeholders from CredHub, shouldn't those automatically update? Unfortunately no. The Diego lifecycle is responsible for looking up CredHub place holders and resolving them. This runs prior to your application starting. It then puts the actual value into `VCAP_SERVICES`. This is how your app can see the actual value and not the place holders, while simultaneously not having any knowledge about CredHub.

Comment: sorry to disturb u but can u look into this
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/issues/17

Comment: Thanks @Daniel : `VCAP_SERVICES` for credhub-stuff doesn't hold the value of actual-credentials, rather point with `"credhub-ref": "/credhub-service-broker/credhub/f96e4398-9784-4224-a568-c81XXXXX/credentials"` . I was guessing it to refer the credentials, whenever requested and can be easily rotated without `app-restart`

Comment: `VCAP_SERVICES for credhub-stuff doesn't hold the value of actual-credentials` -> It depends where you look :)  If you look in Cloud Controller, then you're right. If you look at the value in your app container then no. The Diego lifecycle is responsible for looking up CredHub place holders & resolving them. It then puts the actual value into `VCAP_SERVICES`. This is how your app can see the actual value & not the place holder, while not having any knowledge about CredHub.

Comment: I did `cf ssh <app-name>` and executed `echo VCAP_SERVICES` ... Still I wasn’t able to see the credentials l, rather only credhubref was there

Comment: I think there's two ways you could see the actual values. 1.) Run `cf ssh "<app>" -t -c "/tmp/lifecycle/launcher /home/vcap/app bash ''"`, which uses the launcher to start your bash shell. 2.) Look at use `cf ssh`, then look at `cat /proc/<pid>/environ` where `pid` is the process id of your app process.